# Function to change all variables of factor type to lower case

Tags: r

I need to create a function in order to change all my factor variables to lower case.

I've already done that:

```
change_lower=function(x){if(is.factor(x)) tolower(x)}
```

But I think I'm doing something wrong, maybe the if isn't good for what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Change `tolower(x)` to `tolower(as.character(x))`

Comment: The = sign is not used in an assignment.  The = sign should be changed to the assignment sign  <-

Comment: @Gray `=` is not recommended, but stills works

Comment: Thanks for you quick answers ! So that what I wrote on my R command : change_lower <- function(x){if(is.factor(x)) tolower(as.character(x))}
But when I create an other object with this function from my initial data.frame it still gives me an empty values. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Can you post the output of this in your original post `dput(insert_dataframe__object_name)`? this will make it easier for us to know whats going on in your dataframe.

Comment: `rapply(iris,toupper,"factor",how="replace")`

Comment: This is a sample of the output : 38L, 38L, 28L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
    38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L[...] .Label = c("?", "Cambodia", "Canada", 
    "China", "Columbia", "Cuba" [...] "Philippines", 
    "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto-Rico", "Scotland", "South", 
    "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Trinadad&Tobago", "United-States", 
    "Vietnam", "Yugoslavia"), class = "factor"), target = structure [...]
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("<=50K", 
    ">50K"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5730L))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutate_if` if you want to automatically convert a large number of columns. Be sure to convert to `character` first (as @DanY pointed out):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("A","B","C"), z = c("i","K","l"))
df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, function(x) tolower(as.character(x)))
```

In base R:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("A","B","C"), z = c("i","K","l"))

ind <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.factor)] 
for (i in ind){
  df[[i]] <- tolower(as.character(df[[i]]))
}
```

or

```
df[,ind] <- lapply(ind, function(x) tolower(as.character(df[[x]])))
```

Comment: Do you have a solution without using the dplyr lybrary ? My data.frame has 14 variables and 5000 obs.

Comment: you do not need a for loop. First when using `mutate_if` do `df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, ~tolower(as.character(.x)))` or something similar with piping, 2nd use `lapply` class in base R. ie `rapply(iris,tolower,"factor",how="replace")`

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for pointing out other options to achieve the same goal

Answer (score 0):

```
# Input data: 

df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c("A","B","C"), z = c("i","K","l"))

# Convert factors to lowercase: 

df <- lapply(df, function(x){if(is.factor(x)) as.factor(tolower(as.character(x))) else x})

# Proof: 

str(df)
```